# Додать к коду Java script который использует JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Помогите пожалуйста привести код к виду, который мне нужно будет сдать до дедлайна в универе. Максимум, что я смогла, это написать сайт на html/css. Но есть условия, которые проект должен содержать.
Применять собственно разработан Java script который использует JSON для создания части страницы, вывести данные имеющиися в JSON в виде таблицы или любого объекта что повторяется. Можно использовать фреймворки, но исключительно node.js
что все это значит, я не очень понимаю, а времени мало. мне нужно хоть что-то на скрипте с условиями описанными выше
документы с кодом моего сайта прикреплены.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Taviraj:400,500,700&display=swap');
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Taviraj', serif;
  color: #222;
}

.navbar-brad img {
  width: 150px
}

.navbar-nav li {
  padding-right: 90px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.4em !important
}

.carousel-inner img {
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  transform: translateY(-80%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000;
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .carousel-caption .display-2 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}

.jumbotron {
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.padding {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.alert {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.alert hr {
  border-top: 2px solid silver;
  width: 95%;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#fixed {
  height: 400px;
  border-top: 4px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f0f0f0;
  background: url("../img/1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-color: lightblue;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Beauty salon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Шапка сайту -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brad"><img src="img/01.png"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
    <span class="#navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Про нас</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Послуги</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Фотогалерея</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Відгуки</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Контакти</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Слайдер зображень -->
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="slides">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="img/02.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1 class="display-2">Beauty salon</h1>
        <h3>Запишіться на послугу прямо зараз</h3>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-lg">Записатись</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Партнери</button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/new.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/04.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Головний блок -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row jumbotron">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-10">
        <p class="lead">Ми пропонуємо всі види перукарських послуг: стрижки, вечірні, весільні зачіски, фарбування, мілірування, колорування, тонування, догляд за волоссям, корекцію (камуфлювання) сивини у мужчин, "стійке вкладання" волосся, манікюр, покриття нігтів
          гель-лаком, парафінотерапія рук, педикюр, воскову та цукрову депіляцію, косметоглогічні послуги, візаж, безболісне проколювання вух. Ми використовуємо виключно високоякісні матеріали з ретельним дотриманням технології. Наші послуги доступні
          для широкого кола відвідувачів. Ми знаємо: якість обслуговування – це наша найкраща реклама.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
        <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-succes btn-lg">Дізнатись більше</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Блок з характеристиками -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center alert">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h4 class="display-4">Косметика</h4>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="col-12">
        <p class="lead">Наш салон працює на професійній косметиці Wella Professionals, Goldwell, Peggy Sage - Paris, OPI, Cucco, Baehr, dr. Kraut, BeautyHall, Demax.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Проста секція з зображенням -->
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row padding">
      <div class="offset-lg-2 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Акції та знижки</h2>
        <p>Наш салон вітає Вас, і дарує -10% на будь-які послуги салону!Знижка не розповсюджується на придбання косметики.Увага! Акція діє за день, та в день Вашого народження. Знижка надається за умови, що послуга надається в робочий час салону.Обов’язково
          мати документ для підтвердження дати!<br>- чудову можливість привітати своїх близьких та знайомих. Подарунковий сертифікат дає право пред'явнику розрахуватись за послуги чи придбаний товар.Термін дії сертифікату - 6 місяців з моменту придбання.
          Номінал - від 150,00 грн.</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Читати більше</a>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="img/6.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Блок з фіксацією зображення -->
  <figure>
    <div class="fixed-wrap">
      <div id="fixed">
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class=""="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#gifs">Відкрити блок</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**JSON**

```
"services" : [
    "Манікюр",
    "Перукарські послуги",
    "СПА",
    "Косметологія",
    "Візаж"
    ]
}

{
    "about_us" : [
    "Новини",
    "Про салон",
    "Дипломи",
    "Віртуальний тур"
    ]
}
```

этого будет достаточно

Comment: @MaximLensky , добавила json

Comment: @MaximLensky функционал любой, что-нибудь вообще) не весь, частично что то на js, чтобы инфу з сервера использывал сайт, чтобы в коде был хоть намек на это

Comment: @MaximLensky то есть мне к каждому созданному объекту в своем коде html сделать json в таком виде как в примере? извините за глупый вопрос

Comment: @MaximLensky если я сделаю так как в вашем первом примере, то так подойдет? )

Comment: вот я хотел вам показать на вашем компе как парсить json хоть на jquery хоть на нативном js или же используя это красиво на неком плагине

Comment: @MaximLensky, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу что json должен задуман таким:

```
{
 "services" : [
    "Манікюр",
    "Перукарські послуги",
    "СПА",
    "Косметологія",
    "Візаж"
    ],
 "about_us" : [
    "Новини",
    "Про салон",
    "Дипломи",
    "Віртуальний тур"
    ]
}
```

В ваш html я вставил тег script c таким кодом:

```
window.onload = () => {
// c помощью JSON.parse парсим json строку в объект
const dataFromJson = JSON.parse(`
{"services" : [
    "Манікюр",
    "Перукарські послуги",
    "СПА",
    "Косметологія",
    "Візаж"
 ],
    "about_us" : [
    "Новини",
    "Про салон",
    "Дипломи",
    "Віртуальний тур"
]}`)
//#forJson это селектор элемента в который вы хотите вставить данные из json 
const elem = document.querySelector('#forJson')

//здесь название каждого сервиса оборачивается в элемент <p> и вставляется в раннее выбраный elem  
elem.innerHTML = dataFromJson.services.map(service => `<p>${service}</p>`).join('')
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Taviraj:400,500,700&display=swap');
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Taviraj', serif;
  color: #222;
}

.navbar-brad img {
  width: 150px
}

.navbar-nav li {
  padding-right: 90px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.4em !important
}

.carousel-inner img {
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.carousel-caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  transform: translateY(-80%);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #000;
}

@media (max-width: 450px) {
  .carousel-caption .display-2 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
}

.jumbotron {
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.padding {
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.alert {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.alert hr {
  border-top: 2px solid silver;
  width: 95%;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#fixed {
  height: 400px;
  border-top: 4px solid #f0f0f0;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #f0f0f0;
  background: url("../img/1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-color: lightblue;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}

Дальше я в ваш код добавил так script:
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Beauty salon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
  <script>
window.onload = () => {
// c помощью JSON.parse парсим json строку в объект
const dataFromJson = JSON.parse(`
{"services" : [
    "Манікюр",
    "Перукарські послуги",
    "СПА",
    "Косметологія",
    "Візаж"
 ],
    "about_us" : [
    "Новини",
    "Про салон",
    "Дипломи",
    "Віртуальний тур"
]}`)
//#forJson это селектор элемента в который вы хотите вставить данные из json 
const elem = document.querySelector('#forJson')

//здесь название каждого сервиса оборачивается в элемент <p> и вставляется в раннее выбраный elem  
elem.innerHTML = dataFromJson.services.map(service => `<p>${service}</p>`).join('')
}
</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Шапка сайту -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brad"><img src="img/01.png"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
    <span class="#navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Про нас</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Послуги</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Фотогалерея</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Відгуки</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Контакти</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Слайдер зображень -->
  <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="slides">
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="img/02.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1 class="display-2">Beauty salon</h1>
        <h3>Запишіться на послугу прямо зараз</h3>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-lg">Записатись</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Партнери</button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/new.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="img/04.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Головний блок -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row jumbotron">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-10">
        <p class="lead">Ми пропонуємо всі види перукарських послуг: стрижки, вечірні, весільні зачіски, фарбування, мілірування, колорування, тонування, догляд за волоссям, корекцію (камуфлювання) сивини у мужчин, "стійке вкладання" волосся, манікюр, покриття нігтів
          гель-лаком, парафінотерапія рук, педикюр, воскову та цукрову депіляцію, косметоглогічні послуги, візаж, безболісне проколювання вух. Ми використовуємо виключно високоякісні матеріали з ретельним дотриманням технології. Наші послуги доступні
          для широкого кола відвідувачів. Ми знаємо: якість обслуговування – це наша найкраща реклама.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
        <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-succes btn-lg">Дізнатись більше</button></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Блок з характеристиками -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center alert">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h4 class="display-4">Косметика</h4>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="col-12">
        <p class="lead">Наш салон працює на професійній косметиці Wella Professionals, Goldwell, Peggy Sage - Paris, OPI, Cucco, Baehr, dr. Kraut, BeautyHall, Demax.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Проста секція з зображенням -->
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row padding">
      <div class="offset-lg-2 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Акції та знижки</h2>
        <p>Наш салон вітає Вас, і дарує -10% на будь-які послуги салону!Знижка не розповсюджується на придбання косметики.Увага! Акція діє за день, та в день Вашого народження. Знижка надається за умови, що послуга надається в робочий час салону.Обов’язково
          мати документ для підтвердження дати!<br>- чудову можливість привітати своїх близьких та знайомих. Подарунковий сертифікат дає право пред'явнику розрахуватись за послуги чи придбаний товар.Термін дії сертифікату - 6 місяців з моменту придбання.
          Номінал - від 150,00 грн.</p>
        <br>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Читати більше</a>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="img/6.jpg" class="img-fluid">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="forJson"></div>
  <!-- Блок з фіксацією зображення -->
  <figure>
    <div class="fixed-wrap">
      <div id="fixed">
      </div>
    </div>
  </figure>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class=""="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#gifs">Відкрити блок</button>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: можно так сделать, что когда я нажимаю на пункт "Про нас" "Послуги" отображался выпадающий список с данными из json? или он по другому используется. Просто я не понимаю как это все должно работать на сайте

Comment: нужно чтобы сайт взаимодействовал с сервером, а для этого мы используем json, я так понимаю. Но как это привести к рабочему виду? и был  функциональный сайт

Comment: @УлянаШило вот я хотел вам показать на вашем компе как парсить json хоть на jquery хоть на нативном js или же используя это красиво на неком плагине